# How to show JBox2D object in android activity?

Tags: android, jbox2d

I write a code for showing circle body by using jbox2D. But when is run this code i got blank screen. Now how to show this rigid body on screen. is i need to use any view for showing it on screen ?please help..

```
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.CircleShape;
import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyDef;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyType;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.FixtureDef;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.World;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FirstBox2DGameActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//       setContentView(R.layout.main);     
        Vec2 gravity = new Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f);
        boolean doSleep = true;
        World world = new World(gravity, doSleep);

        // Body definition is created as below.
        BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
        bd.position.set(100, 200);
        bd.type = BodyType.STATIC;

        // body Shape
        CircleShape cs = new CircleShape();
        cs.m_radius = 5.0f;

        // Fixture defines the material properties of the body. Fixtures are
        // also used for attaching shape to the body. These material properties
        // describe how two bodies should react when they collide with each
        // other.
        FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
        fd.shape = cs;
        fd.density = 0.5f;
        fd.friction = 0.3f;
        fd.restitution = 0.5f;

        // Now final step is to create a body and add fixture to it. The bodies
        // are created using World class.
        Body body = world.createBody(bd);
        body.createFixture(fd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you do have to draw it on screen as well. :) see example here http://disanji.net/2010/12/18/android-2d-box2d/